# Redirect all network of Android App (which is using Libraries) through a proxy network (if available)

Tags: java, android, networking, proxy, http-proxy

I am working on an Android application and I am using various libraries like Picaso, Retrofit, Crashlytics, etc. and my college WIFI have proxy on it.

I know how to use a proxy when sending a HTTP requests to a server, but all the libraries that I am using have there own HTTP requests, so overriding all their HTTP classes would be a headache, and I am not even sure how to do that.

So, is there a way to route all the traffic of the App through a proxy (when available), like any library or some HTTP request overriding all the outgoing requests.

Comment: You get it to work? I am looking for a way to redirect all applications traffic through a proxy. Is this possible?

Comment: @sak See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this as below.
(I forgot the original source).

```
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.ProxySelector;

//setting Application-Wide proxy Values
private void setProxy() {
    //Device proxy settings
    ProxySelector defaultProxySelector = ProxySelector.getDefault();
    Proxy proxy = null;
    List<Proxy> proxyList = defaultProxySelector.select(URI.create("http://www.google.in"));
    if (proxyList.size() > 0) {
        proxy = proxyList.get(0);

        Log.d("proxy", String.valueOf(proxy));

        try {
            String proxyType = String.valueOf(proxy.type());

            //setting HTTP Proxy
            if (proxyType.equals("HTTP")) {
                String proxyAddress = String.valueOf(proxy.address());
                String[] proxyDetails = proxyAddress.split(":");
                String proxyHost = proxyDetails[0];
                String proxyPort = proxyDetails[1];
                Log.d("proxy", proxyType + " " + proxyHost + " " + proxyPort);

                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Put this method in your base activity's onCreate method so it will get executed everytime user opens the application.

Comment: Also visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https if having certificate issues.

Comment: Thanks but This code seems to be  application specific, right? It will not redirect all device traffic via that proxy?

Comment: Yes. It will direct only the specific application data through the proxy.

Comment: All device traffic -- we have vpn for that

Comment: The inbuilt VPN option in settings of device will redirect all device traffic or  I have to create or use any custom VPN app?

Comment: This code will direct your particular application's traffic through proxy, i.e. proxyHost:proxyPort. No need for any other VPN or other settings.

Comment: hello, should this code work also for proxies outside your network? let's say commercial ones

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect specific network traffic (on a per application basis) as per the following link.

[Network traffic via Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290970/how-to-make-all-network-traffic-go-via-a-proxy?rq=1)